# Your belt is open/untied/is undone

Tags: word-usage

If we have to tell someone that their belt is unfastened (a person did that before but now it's come undone)

> Your belt's open/untied/undone.

What would sound natural?

> No my belt is tied/closed/fastened.
>   (If a person doesn't realize it and feels that his/her belt isn't untied)

The belt can be either be a buckle one or the one that has a hook and is elastic (what girls wear with skirts).

Comment: "Open" or "Undone." "Untied" would only work if the belt was a tied together piece of rope or something.

Comment: "Unfastened" or "undone". Not "open". "Untied" only if it is a fabric sash, or some kind of "rope" type belt that you would literally tie (with a knot or a bow) around your waist.

Comment: What's wrong with using unfastened as you have said in your opening line? "Your belt has become unfastened"

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to hear any of the given words for any type of belt. In my experience, when you start with "your belt..." 99% of people will immediately look to see if it's undone, and the following word hardly matters.

Comment: "Not on properly" would also work if you are unsure of the 3 options you provided.

Comment: For the second question, I'd have to say by far the most natural response would be "No it's not"/"No it isn't." If you're too distracted to check whether your belt's actually undone, you're certainly not going to put that much thought into your reply.

Answer (score 2):

I think "undone" sounds most natural. I've said that and I've heard people say it. I've never heard anyone say "open" or "unfastened."

I've also jokingly said after realizing my belt was undone, "should probably do up my belt."